# How to compare the slope of interaction variables in mixed effect model in r

Tags: r, glm, random-effects

I want to test the effects of island area and land use, and the interaction between island area and land use on species richness. For land use, I have three groups, namely forest, farmland and mix. The data is based on transects on different islands, so the island ID is set as random effect.

My model looks like this:

```
#model = glmer(SR ~ Area + land_use + Area:land_use + (1|islandID))

#summary(model)

Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: SR ~ Area + land_use + Area:land_use + (1 | islandID)
Data: transect_ZS

REML criterion at convergence: 184.4

Scaled residuals: 
 Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.66105 -0.56159 -0.00294  0.57259  1.72096 

Random effects:
Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
islandID (Intercept) 0.1524   0.3903  
Residual             0.6805   0.8249  
Number of obs: 70, groups:  islandID, 34

Fixed effects:
                 Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)         -0.9996   0.5187 57.0061  -1.927  0.05893 . 
Area                0.9064    0.2834 40.9977   3.198  0.00267 **
land_useforest      0.6563    0.5569 62.0889   1.179  0.24309   
land_usemix         0.9611    0.6373 55.3032   1.508  0.13723   
Area:land_useforest -0.8318   0.3034 63.4045  -2.742  0.00793 **
Area:land_usemix    -0.7756   0.4748 56.3692  -1.633  0.10795   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The results told me that island area and the interaction terms have significant effect on SR:

```
#    > anova(model)
#Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
#                Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF  DenDF F value  Pr(>F)  
#Area                 3.0359 3.03590     1 27.448  4.4615 0.04390 *
#land_use             1.5520 0.77601     2 57.617  1.1404 0.32679  
#Area:land_use        5.1658 2.58288     2 60.935  3.7958 0.02795 *
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
```

And then I used lsmeans function to conduct Tukeys' pairwise comparison:

```
#lsmeans(model, pairwise ~ Area:land_use, adjust="tukey")
```

The results indicate that the species richness from farmland and forest is significantly different, right? I wonder if this difference should be seen as the significant difference of intercept of the species richness-area relationship between farmland and forest in this model? That is the species richness from farmland transects is higher than that from forest transects?

```
#$contrasts
  contrast                                            estimate    SE   df t.ratio p.value
 1.19968425045037 farmland - 1.19968425045037 forest   3.4153 0.288 62.6   1.185  0.0466
 1.19968425045037 farmland - 1.19968425045037 mix     -0.0306 0.426 64.0  -0.072  0.9972
 1.19968425045037 forest - 1.19968425045037 mix       -0.3722 0.377 63.9  -0.987  0.5087

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates
```

But how to test if the slope of the species richness-area relationship between farmland and forest in this model is significant different? That is to testify if the species richness-area relationship from farmland transects is more steeper than that from forest transect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

```
lstrends(model, pairwise ~ land_use, var = "Area", adjust="tukey")
```

The functions `lsmeans` and `lstrends` are in the **emmeans** package, in which they are equivalent to `emmeans` and `emtrends` respectively. So look at the documentation for those functions. The **lsmeans** package is just a front end.